# How to 3rd party routing to my component?

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, joomla-4.x, routing

I need to add EasySocial routing to my own component, so that `JRoute([some EasySocial link])` outputs a proper EasySocial URL.

How can I do that? If I understand correctly, EasySocial routing is active only and only while I'm on the EasySocial component - I just need to make that routing available for my own component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears EasySocial requires menu item ID to be appended to the non-SEF URL passed to `JRoute::_()` call. There is `ESR::getItemId()` method that can retrieve the menu item ID of a given view. So something like this could work:

```
JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_easysocial&view=albums&Itemid=' . ESR::getItemId('albums'))
```

However, the most common way is to use magic static methods of `ESR` class. This is what EasySocial and the included modules generally used. The method name is the view and it accepts an array of arguments:

```
ESR::albums(['layout' => 'default', 'id' => $someId]);
```

Before you can use EasySocial classes, you need to load `easysocial.php` file:

```
$engine = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_easysocial/includes/easysocial.php';

if (!is_file($engine)) {
    // EasySocial is not installed, return early or use some fallback code
}

require_once $engine;
```